# Update 4 fields on a one record based on the values in 4 related records?

Tags: governorlimits

I am looking for the most efficient way to modify a single record based on the result of 4 specific records.

Specifically we are using a custom fiscal period system.  This means that every date field has 4 potential records on the "Period" object.  (Year, Quarter, Month, Week).  For Opportunity.closeDate I want to capture the appropriate values for each of these records.

Currently the only way I can think do to do this.

1. On Update if Oppty = new or closedate is changed
2. For each updated opportunities Select Period records whose start and end date straddle the opportunity closeDate
3. For each Period Record update the appropriate field on the opportunity (e.g. Year, Quarter, etc)
4. Add the updated opportunity to a list
5. Update Opportunities in the list

Cardinal sin of a query in a for loop, but I can't figure out how to make this work with maps, etc.

Comment: an example would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to abuse the equals function by creating a special DateRange class. See the [Using Custom Types in Maps and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm) to see more information about what I'm actually doing.

Allow me to demonstrate the class you'd want to use:

```
class DateRange {
    Date startDate, endDate;
    DateRange(Date first, Date last) {
        startDate = first;
        endDate = last;
    }
    DateRange(Date firstAndLast) {
        startDate = endDate = firstAndLast;
    }
    public Boolean equals(Object rangeObj) {
        DateRange other = (DateRange)rangeObj;
        return startDate <= other.endDate && endDate >= other.startDate;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

At this point, you can either build a dynamic query, or, more likely, just choose to query for the ranges that interest you min/max style (should be okay in most orgs).

```
Opportunity[] oppsToProcess = new Opportunity[0];
Date minDate, maxDate;
for(Integer index = 0, size = Trigger.new.size(); index < size; index++) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.new[index].CloseDate != Trigger.old[index].CloseDate) {
       if(minDate == null || minDate > Trigger.new[index].CloseDate) {
           minDate = Trigger.new[index].CloseDate;
       }
       if(maxDate == null || maxDate < Trigger.new[index].CloseDate) {
           maxDate = Trigger.new[index].CloseDate;
       }
       oppsToProcess.add(Trigger.new[index]);
    }
}
Map<DateRange, Period> yearRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>(),
                       monthRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>(),
                       quarterRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>(),
                       weekRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>();
for(Period record: [SELECT StartDate, Name, EndDate, Type FROM Period WHERE StartDate <= :maxDate AND EndDate >= :minDate]) {
    if(record.Type == 'year') {
        yearRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
    } else if(record.Type == 'quarter') {
        quarterRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
    } else if(record.Type == 'month') {
        monthRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
    } else {
        weekRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
    }
}
```

Finally, just loop back over the opportunities to process and grab your data:

```
for(Opportunity record: oppsToProcess) {
    Period yearPeriod = yearRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate)),
           quarterPeriod = quarterRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate)),
           monthPeriod = monthRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate)),
           weekPeriod = weekRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate));
    // Do field updates, etc here.
}
```

The dynamic query would look much the same way, but dynamically. Unless you have opportunities being closed that span dozens of years, using min/max should have respectable performance.

Finally, you could do the same thing "manually", basically building lists of periods, and iterating over them for every opportunity to update, but nested loops are not as efficient as using a custom map key for larger quantities of records. Although in the usual case, you probably wouldn't end up with too many periods in a typical trigger context, so that would probably be okay as well.

Comment: Really cool approach.  I did run into one issue while implementing, probably a noob failure.   I will post another answer with this in it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it took me a while to understand what the code was doing.  Once I go it (I think) I have tried to set it up in my sandbox.  I am getting the error "Field Expression not allowed for generic SObject"  which doesn't make sense for how this is set up.  Screen shot and full code below.

[image: FiscalPeriodClassError]

```
public class GetFiscalPeriodInfo_v2 {
Opportunity[] oppsToProcess = new Opportunity[0];

public static void CreateFP(Opportunity[] oppsToProcess) { 
    Date minDate, maxDate;
    for(Integer index = 0, size = Trigger.new.size(); index < size; index++) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.new[index].CloseDate != Trigger.old[index].CloseDate) {
            if(minDate == null || minDate > Trigger.new[index].CloseDate) {
                minDate = Trigger.new[index].CloseDate;
            }
            if(maxDate == null || maxDate < Trigger.new[index].CloseDate) {
                maxDate = Trigger.new[index].CloseDate;
            }
            oppsToProcess.add(Trigger.new[index]);
        }
    }

    Map<DateRange, Period> yearRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>(),
        monthRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>(),
        quarterRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>(),
        weekRange = new Map<DateRange, Period>();
    for(Period record: [SELECT Type,PeriodLabel,Number,startDate,endDate FROM Period WHERE StartDate <= :maxDate AND EndDate >= :minDate]) {
        if(record.Type == 'year') {
            yearRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
        } else if(record.Type == 'quarter') {
            quarterRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
        } else if(record.Type == 'month') {
            monthRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
        } else {
            weekRange.put(new DateRange(record.StartDate, record.EndDate), record);
        }
    }

    list<Opportunity> OpptyUpdate=new list<Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity record: oppsToProcess) {
        Period yearPeriod = yearRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate)),
            quarterPeriod = quarterRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate)),
            monthPeriod = monthRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate)),
            weekPeriod = weekRange.get(new DateRange(record.CloseDate));
        Opportunity Oppty = new Opportunity();
        Oppty.Close_Fiscal_Month__c=monthPeriod;
        Oppty.Close_Fiscal_Quarter__c=quarterPeriod;
        Oppty.Close_Fiscal_Week__c=weekPeriod;
        Oppty.Close_Fiscal_Year__c=yearPeriod;

        OpptyUdate.add(Oppty);
    }

    Try{
        update OpptyUpdate;
    }catch(DmlException e){
        System.debug('An error has occurred: '+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}